# search bar not working and cant select row from table

Tags: ios

I cant select  row from  table data and also cant access search bar via search bar display.When i run this it don't select any row, only dismiss tableview ..i connect search bar with file owner.Below i am showing all methods Could any one help me??

```
@protocol CityListDelegate<NSObject>

        -(void)returnCityName:(NSString*)cityName;



        @end
        @interface CityViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
        {
            int index;
            //NSArray *cityList;

        }

        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *cityTableView;
         @property(nonatomic, retain)id<CityListDelegate> delegate;

        @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *SearchCityResult;
        @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *CityList;
        /////.m file


        @synthesize CityList;








        #pragma mark Table view methods
        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {


            if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
            {
                return [self.SearchCityResult count];
            }
            else
            {
                return [self.CityList count];
            }

        }
        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if(cell==nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
            if (tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
            {



                cell.textLabel.text = [self.SearchCityResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            }
            else
            {
                cell.textLabel.text = self.CityList [indexPath.row];
            }




            return cell;

        }




        -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)IndexPath
        {

            if (tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
            {

                [self.delegate returnCityName:[self.SearchCityResult objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row]];

            }
            else
            {
                [self.delegate returnCityName:[CityList objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row]];
            }


           [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


        }
        - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
        {
            [self.SearchCityResult removeAllObjects];
            NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];

            self.SearchCityResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self.CityList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
        }

        -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
        {
            [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

            return YES;
        }
```

Comment: Check your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)IndexPath`method if it is correctly named - I am pretty sure `IndexPath` should be `indexPath`

Comment: "When i run this it don't select any row, only dismiss tableview", can you clear this?

Comment: i also in same problem .I cant select any row..

Comment: Could any one help??

Answer (score 0):

Be more precise about the setup, did you use the storyboard?

And make sure you use the right delegate methods. Looks like you named the indexPath paramter of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` wrong, should be indexPath.